# Basic regression model in R assistance

Tags: r

I am starting to dig into R and teach myself the basics, and I wanted to look into getting help with a few commands.

I'm trying to understand the following concepts using a dataset pulled from a text file:

For starters, here is the first few lines of the text document in question:

```
salary      totcomp   tenure  age     sales   profits   assets  Industry
24222.39    58936.87    7     61      161315    2956    257389  2
24048.97    59219.46    0     51      144416    22071   237545  3
23172.99    56814.47    11    63      139208    4430    49271   2
23431.15    56971.3     6     60      100697    6370    92630   3
22049.87    55596.23    18    63      100469    9296    355935  3
```

**Create correlation table**

```
salary<-read.table(file="C:/Users/sean/Desktop/ceosalary.txt", header = TRUE,sep="\t")
attach(salary)
cor(salary[-c(1,4,6)])
```

**Build multiple regression model**

```
 lm(formula = profits - Industry)
 o1<-lm(salary-profits)
```

When executing `lm()` an error occurs:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = salary - profits, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : invalid type (list) for variable 'salary'

**Obtain an anova table**

For the above multiple regression model, using `anova()`:

```
anova(lm)
```

Am I on the right track with these commands?

Comment: What is the model you wish to fit? Are you trying to predict salary based on profits? then you want `lm(salary~profits)` not `lm(salary-profits)` -- note the tilde "~" rather than a minus sign. The former is used to specify formulas in R. Also, i would suggest avoiding `attach()`. It can really mess up your search path quickly and most functions have a `data=` parameter so it's just not necessary. For example: `lm(salary~profits, data=salary)`

Comment: Also to print the ANOVA tables for a fitted regreesion model, use e.g., `fit <- lm(salary~profits, data=salary)` to capture the fitted model and then `anova(fit)` to display the ANOVA table. It also seems to me that `Industry` is supposed to be a categorical variable. In this case you should convert it to a factor using `salary$Industry <- factor(salary$Industry)` before fitting a model with it.

Comment: No, I am trying to predict Profits based on Industry, then sales, then age.

Comment: The profits are the independent variable.

Comment: Sounds like you have independent and dependent backwards. If you're trying to predict profits based on industry, sales and age, don't you think that profits *depend* on those other variables?   The model then would be `fit <- lm(profits ~ Industry + sales + age, data = salary)`.

Comment: And, at a glance, you probably want to convert `salary$Industry <- as.factor(salary.Indusrty)` to treat `Industry` categorically. Unless `Industry` 3 is 3/2 "more" than `Industry` 2.

Answer (score 2):

Your model is not a multiple regression model. Its a simple linear regression. Also the formula for lm function be of the form y~x and not y-x. Here y will be the dependent variable and x will be the independent variable.

In R, you should code like this:

```
fit <-  lm(profits~Industry, data=salary)
summary(fit)
```

If you want to do multiple regression,

```
fit <- lm(profits~Industry+tenure+age, data=salary)
summary(fit)
```

summary(fit) will give you the output of the model with the p-values, regression coefficients, residual standard error and many other things.

For doing anova, you should do:

```
anova(fit)
```